# Multiple if condition in bash not working

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have written the following bash script:

```
if [ "crack" == "crack" -a "something/play" == *"play"* ];
then
     echo "Passed"
else
     echo "Failed"
fi
```

However the right side of this comparison is not working.
I noticed that if I use it the only right side with `[[ "something/play" == *"play"* ]]` it works correctly but how do I combine the two conditions inside the if clause.

Comment: `if [[ "crack" == "crack" ]]; then if [[ -e "something/play" &&  something/play == *"play"* ]]; then foo; else bar; fi; fi`  Maybe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a difference between `[` and `[[`. The first is a standard command, where `=` just tests for equality. (Note that the standard operator is `=`, not `==`.) The latter is a feature from ksh, supported in Bash and Zsh, and *there*, `=`/`==` is a pattern match. Also, you should avoid using `-a` within `[ .. ]`, it can break if you do something like `[ "$a" = foo -a "$b" = bar ]` and `$a` or `$b` contains a `!`.

So,

```
$ if [[ "crack" == "crack" && "something/play" == *"play"* ]]; then echo true; fi
true
```

See also (in unix.SE): [Why is `[` a shell builtin and `[[` a shell keyword?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/why-is-a-shell-builtin-and-a-shell-keyword) and [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs).

Answer (score 1):

If you use double brackets you can chain conditions with `&&` (and) and `||` (or).

```
if [[ "crack" == "crack" && "something/play" == *"play"* ]]
then
     echo "Passed"
else
     echo "Failed"
fi
```